# Assigning child object to the base is possible, But if do the same with the collection it is not possible

Tags: java, c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Assigning child object to the base is possible.

```
base1 b1 = new child1();
```

But if we do the same with the collection it is not possible, Why?

```
List<base1> libase = new List<child1>();
```

Any reference having this explanation is very helpful, please share

```
        public class base1
        {

        }
        public class child1 : base1
        {

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            base1 b1 = new child1();
            List<base1> libase = new List<child1>();
            Console.Read();   
        }
```

Comment: Jorn, this is C# not Java

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks, was not able to find out anything related to this

Comment: @dahui The question is also tagged with Java, besides the explanation is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c# you can do such trick:

```
List<base1> libase = new List<base1>(new List<child1>());
```

Also, you can use Interface IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<base1> libase = new List<child1>();
```

Because it's declared as:

```
  public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
  {
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
  }
```

`out T` it the most important.

When List is just:

```
public class List<T>
{}
```

About your question read more here [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)